# SharpYaml custom parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, yaml

I was looking for a custom parser example for SharpYaml but I only found solutions via serialization. 
But I need to parse a class the custom way.

This is the class i need to parse

```
 public class CommunicationMessage {

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<CommunicationMessage> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

And this should be an example output:

```
employee:
    - name: Martin
    - job: Developer
    - skill: Elite
    - languages:
        - c#
        - java
        - php
```

If the list itself is empty or null the value should be written, otherwise the list should be parsed.
Hope this helps understanding my question

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is this *Custom Way* and what did you try yet?

Comment: I tried to find some examples, but found nothing. The custom way is that the class contains a List **Childs** which should be serialized to a different key. I did the same thing with Json.Net, but I cannot find a way to do the same with SharpYaml

Comment: Have a look at [YamlRemapAttribute](https://github.com/xoofx/SharpYaml/blob/master/SharpYaml/Serialization/YamlRemapAttribute.cs). This seems to fit your needs

Comment: Is there a little example on how to use it?

Comment: If you dont know how Attributes work, i barely believe you chievend your goal with JSON. SO is not a Codewriting Service. Please show what you have already tried and where you are stuck

Comment: I know how to use Attributes, but I think I have expressed myself wrong. Updating the question

Comment: You are talking about a list, but there is no list in your YAML. There also seems to be no connection at all between the C# code you show and your YAML structure. You should show a minimal example that constructs the in-memory data structure, so that we can see how you want to map it to the desired YAML output.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

Your example output suggests that there is a list of mappings. It should probably look like this:

```
employee:
  name: Martin
  job: Developer
  skill: Elite
  languages:
  - c#
  - java
  - php
```

As far as I understand the question, you want to serialize CommunicationMessage.
Each CommunicationMessage object represents one key-to-value mapping, which can have two different kinds of values: A scalar(string) or a list of mappings.

What I don't understand is how this in-memory structure would represent a yaml array. You see, each entry in the list "Childs" is a CommunicationMessage, so it has a Key, whereas the example output shows an array under "languages", which doesn't have any keys, only values.

Once you manage to fix the in-memory representation (by allowing array and dictionary-like values), you can loop over the memory model and use an *Emitter* to serialize the data.

That works a lot the same way as how it would be done for json, although SharpYaml appears to support something called yaml streams, and I don't know what those are:

EDIT: Below example code does not work. It doesn't use the right *ParsingEvent*s in the right places. I can't figure this bit out.

```
public class EmitterStuff
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> toSerialize = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        // Add values


        // Use following code as an example to serialize the in-memory data
        string yaml;
        using (TextWriter output = new StringWriter())
        {
            IEmitter emitter = new Emitter(output);
            emitter.Emit(new DocumentStart());
            WriteYamlObject(emitter, toSerialize);
            emitter.Emit(new DocumentEnd(false));
            yaml = output.ToString();
        }

        // result is in yaml
    }

    private static void WriteYamlObject(IEmitter emitter, object obj)
    {
        if (obj is IDictionary<string, object>)
        {
            emitter.Emit(new MappingStart());

            var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>) obj;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in dict)
            {
                emitter.Emit(new Scalar(pair.Key));
                WriteYamlObject(emitter, pair.Value);
            }

            emitter.Emit(new MappingEnd());
        }
        else if (obj is ICollection<object>)
        {
            emitter.Emit(new SequenceStart());

            var coll = (ICollection<object>) obj;
            foreach (object value in coll)
            {
                WriteYamlObject(emitter, value);
            }

            emitter.Emit(new SequenceEnd());
        }
        else
        {
            // You probably should have some special cases here.
            emitter.Emit(new Scalar(obj.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```